# Caching a pandas dataframe in Heroku

Tags: django, pandas, heroku

I use pandas in my Django app running on Heroku using Heroku Postgres.

I have a reporting page, where I create a dataframe by reading a number of db tables and performing calculations on it. The resulting dataframe has about 100000 rows and 70 columns.

I then run a pivot on the dataframe to summarise the data based on user input. If the user wants to summarise (pivot) the data by another field, I then have to recalculate the entire dataframe which can take up to 10 seconds.

To solve this I want to cache the dataframe so that I can quickly run the updated pivot on it and was wondering what my best options are here?

1. Create a temp table in the database to store the results (unsure how
   to do this with Django - will probably have to drop down to raw sql)
2. Save the results using redis Cache (I think this is the way to go but also unsure how to do this)
3. Save data in a S3 bucket (I know how to do this, but I'm sure there are better ways)
4. Something else? Feather/HDF store